# FLEX - make textArea dispatch an event each time a new line is taken?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

Every time a user takes a new line (i.e each time they press the return/enter key) when typing in a textArea, I would like the textArea to dispatch an event.I can then listen for this event and then carry out some processing on the textArea's contents.

Can anyone demo/advise how I can achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Listen for the [keyUp Event](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/InteractiveObject.html#event%3akeyUp) an check to see if the key pressed is [enter](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/ui/Keyboard.html#ENTER).

Answer (score 1):

Re el houser's answer: when dealing with components that have a UITextFields (TextInput, TextArea, etc.), you should try to use the keyDown event.  If a user holds down a key on the keyboard in a TextInput component the keyDown event will be fired multiple times before a single keyUp event is fired.

There is a built-in event you can listen for -- FlexEvent.ENTER is already dispatched from UITextField (i believe).  That should get you on the right path.